# Messed up bookmarks in PDF

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

I need to center the title of the parts in the toc. I'm trying these two approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\centerline{Part A}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section A}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\hfill{Part B}\hfill}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section B}
\end{document}
```

When the PDF is generated, the bookmarks have some of problems:

1. Part A appears in the bookmarks as "toPart A".
2. Part B appears hierarchically under Section A.
3. Part B appears correctly in the bookmarks, but it's not correctly centered in the page.

What can I do to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: The content of `\hfill` etc. is not allowed in the bookmarks. Why are you generating such entries manually?

Comment: Christian, I tried to simplify the document to isolate the problems. The real document is much more complex than this. The entries are inserted manually because they can't appear in the document body, only in the toc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\hfill` or `\centerline` is no valid content for the bookmarks. Use `\texorpdfstring{ToC content}{bookmark content}`.

Also use the correct load order: `tocloft`, `hyperref`, `bookmark` to get the correct hierarchy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\centerline {Part A}}{Part A}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\centerline {Part B}}{Part B}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Christian, but the centering has the same problem described in "Part B" of my example: the text is not correctly centered. The centering should consider the area where page numbers appear.

Comment: @ZéCláudio: It's still better than before and I am working on it.

Comment: Yes, it is, Christian. Thank you very much. Based on you help I tried this "\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\centerline{Part A}}{Part A}}" and it is correctly centered now. The only problem is the bookmarks hierarchy.

Comment: Whoa! That's what I needed. Thank you very much, @ChristianHupfer!

Comment: @ZéCláudio: The `bookmark` package is the wizard here!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a good bookmark hierarchy, you should add anchors. And imho the look of the part entries should be set through the tocloft commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}

\renewcommand \cftpartfont     {\hfill}
\renewcommand \cftpartafterpnum{\hfill\mbox{}} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tracingmacros=1
    \tableofcontents
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part A}
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section A}
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part B}
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section B}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\addcontentsline` uses the latest anchor setting for the bookmark.
The example of the question does not contain an explicit anchor setting for the `\addcontentsline` commands, therefore they all share the same latest anchor, in this case the anchor from the begin of the document.

The algorithm for the bookmarks does not work correctly, if there are several bookmarks that share the same anchor. This is fixed by adding package `bookmark`.

An anchor can be set by `\phantomsection` and it should be ensured that the location is correct, because this is the target of the bookmark.
Often the following pattern can be seen:

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{...}
Part stuff.
```

---

Macros like `\centerline` that do not make sense and do not work in bookmarks
can be globally disabled by `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`, e.g.:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\centerline\@firstofone}
```

However, `\centerline` does not look too good inside `\addcontentsline`.
It usually better to change the layout of the table of contents instead (
(e.g. redefining `\l@part` or using a package that deals with the layout of the table of contents).